# Syntax Error at end of input postgresql redshift

Tags: sql, case, amazon-redshift, where-clause

I am currently getting an invalid operation syntax error at the end of my input, and I need help in understanding what i am doing incorrect

```
 SELECT *
 FROM odsCustomerAccount CA
 JOIN ods.house_dim hd ON hd.Customer_Row_id = CA.Customer_row_id
 WHERE '1023545768' = (CASE WHEN 'House' = 'House' THEN hd.MorgageNumber
 WHEN 'Customer Number' = 'Customer Number' THEN CONVERT(varchar, CA.Customer_Number)
 ELSE 'NULL'
 END)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. thank you

Comment: What are the data types of the columns?  Why do you have two conditions that are trivially true?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the Customer Number is an int which is why we are converting it to Varchar in the clause and the MorgageNumber is a varchar

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that `MortgageNumber` is a number and you are getting a type conflict.  This suggests that you should be using:

```
where (:something = 'House' and '1023545768' = hd.MortgageNumber) or
      (:something = 'Customer Number' and '1023545768' = CA.Customer_Number::text)
```

Comment: MortgageNumber is a varchar field so there should be no issue with that